# BoxLayou duplicates on Kivy

Tags: python, layout, kivy, kivy-language

I am designing an app to help in the learning of literacy. My idea is to display a screen similar to the following:[My idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jddbu.jpg)

But when I run, it duplicates, even, quadruples the BoxLayout and I can't find the problem.[The real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrh8i.jpg)

*.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<DrawGame>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Image:
            source: 'data/img/letra_a/a-trazo.png'

<ImageEx>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Image:
            source: 'data/img/letra_a/avestruz.png'
            
<SoundEx>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: [1,.25]
        pos: root.pos
        Label:
            text: "Sonido de ejemplo"
            color: [0,83,80,19]
            
<ContainerBox>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'data/img/fondobosque.jpg'
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'En este juego debes escribir con tu dedo, de manera correcta, la letra por la que empieza la imagen que le acompaña. Además podrás escuchar su pronunciación'
        size_hint_y: 0.2
    BoxLayout:  
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        DrawGame:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                ImageEx:
                SoundEx:
```

*.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Line, Color
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window


Builder.load_file('letras.kv')

class DrawGame(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DrawGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0,1,0,0.5)
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=10)
            
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print(touch)
        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)
        
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("Released!", touch)
        
class ImageEx(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ImageEx, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
class SoundEx(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SoundEx, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
class ContainerBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContainerBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            
class LetrasApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
        return ContainerBox()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    LetrasApp().run()
```

I can't understand why it multiplies all the information, both images and tags. There is only one declaration for each class.

Comment: Try removing the `Builder.load_file('letras.kv')` line. Your `letras.kv` file will be loaded automatically, and loading it explicitly can cause duplication.

Comment: In fact, it was as simple as that, it called the .kv implicitly and automatically, so it loaded it twice. Thank you @JohnAnderson

Comment: It did not work for me - remove the Builder.load causes the interpreter not to be familiar with the class properties